# cURL windows do not display html response

Tags: html, windows, curl, console

Is there any way to not display the html response in the console? It's slowing down my project and I would like to disable it.

I simply use

curl http://www.mysite.com

Thanks

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do it on windows

```
curl "http://example.com" -o NUL
```

This tells curl to download the output to the windows equivalent of `/dev/null`

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the output to /dev/null on unix-like systems or NUL on windows systems. Or just save it to a file that only only check in case something goes wrong.

You redirect the output using the shell operator > or you can use curl's .o (lower case letter o) option.

Answer (score 0):

You could direct the output to /dev/null

```
curl http://www.mysite.com > /dev/null
```

Comment: I assumed he meant windows as in the interface by which cURL is running, not the OS. (Based on him not using the terms 'curl.exe' or 'command prompt'.)